# Migrate onClick from HTML to Javascript file

Tags: javascript, onclick, getelementbyid

In my HTML, this works

```
<div id="portfolio1" onclick="changeMainFrame('lib/portfolio1.html')">
```

to trigger the following function:

```
function changeMainFrame(srcURL){
  var target = document.getElementById("mainFrame");
  target.src = srcURL;
}
```

I want to migrate it to my javascript doc. But this does not work:

```
document.getElementById("portfolio1").onclick = changeMainFrame("lib/portfolio1.html");
```

I can not find out how to fix this. Any hints? Cannot find a similar situation anywhere for something so simple yet time consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("portfolio1").onclick = function() {
  changeMainFrame("lib/portfolio1.html");
}
```

You're calling the function changeMainFrame. What you want to do is supply a function wrapper.

```js
document.getElementById("portfolio1").onclick = function() {
  changeMainFrame("lib/portfolio1.html");
}

function changeMainFrame(txt) {
  alert(txt);
}
```

```html
<div id="portfolio1">Click Me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a function to `document.getElementById("portfolio1").onclick` which will be called when that element gets clicked. The problem is that instead of assigning a function, you assigned the result of invoking/calling that function. What you can do instead is provide a function in which inside it you call `changeMainFrame`:

```
document.getElementById("portfolio1").onclick = function() {
    changeMainFrame("lib/portfolio1.html");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use .onclick or the onclick attribute. Both of them require a handler function, and what you were passing was just the result of running your changeMainFrame function (null). Wrapping it in a `function() {  }` yields your expected result.

```js
function changeMainFrame(srcURL){
  var target = document.getElementById("mainFrame");
  target.src = srcURL;
}
document.getElementById("portfolio1").onclick = function(){changeMainFrame('https://codepen.io')}
```

```html
<div id="portfolio1">go to codepen.io</div>
<iframe id="mainFrame" src="https://example.com"></iframe>
```